# PHP include CSS file but is If or Else needed?

Tags: php, html

Here is my code to include a CSS file my PHP GET. I need to know if the first IF is needed or not. The idea is: If user does not set a existing CSS file by using a form select drop down with method GET or if string is empty the page will display Default.css if the string is ok and the CSS file exist in whitelist then we show echo get `.CSS` file.

In the follow code you see I try to check if string is empty, that is like checking if file is or not in whitelist. Thats the question. Does I need the first if empty funtion? How can I fix this code to work better

```
<?php
$unsafe = $_GET['theme'];
$style = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $unsafe);
if (empty($style)) {
    echo ('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/default.css" />');
}

$whitelist = array('default', 'styleone', 'styletwo', 'another', 'andonemore');

if (isset($whitelist[$style])) {
    echo ('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/' . $style . '.css" />');
} else {
    echo ('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/default.css" />');
}
?>
```

Comment: Where does the user set a CSS file? Is it saved in a database record, or is it a Session variable or set as a cookie?

Comment: It is comming from a drop down menu so the url send it by method GET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not needed, because in second if statement you check it against `$whitelist` and it will echo default style anyway.
You need to change however

```
if (isset($whitelist[$style]))
```

to

```
if (in_array($style, $whitelist))
```

OR

```
$whitelist = array('default', 'styleone', 'styletwo', 'another', 'andonemore');
```

to

```
$whitelist = array('default'=>1, 'styleone'=>1, 'styletwo'=>1, 'another'=>1, 'andonemore=>1');
```

Because you check by keys, not by values of your `$whitelist` array.

You can also assign 'default' to `$style` in case it is empty.

```
if (empty($style)){
    $style = 'default';
}
```

Comment: You are the man! Just one last question. Because the script will not use MySQL and it is using whitelist does I need the preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', for some safety or it is not needed?

Comment: It is not crucial, I would stay whit whitelisting, nothing else will get through behind that.

Answer (score 2):

You can check both in one condition:

```
if (!empty($style) && in_array($style, $whitelist)) {
    echo ('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/' . $style . '.css" />'); 
} else {
    echo ('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/default.css" />');
}
```

Note, that `$whitelist[$style]` doesn't exist, `$style` isn't `key` but `value`. Use `in_array` instead.

Comment: Just one last question. Because the script will not use MySQL and it is using whitelist does I need the preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', for some safety or it is not needed?

Comment: @Grupo456436657: if there is whitelist and you use `in_array`, you can remove `preg_replace` function. You can make code lighter using directly `$_GET['theme']`. `if (isset($_GET['theme']) && in_array($_GET['theme'], $whitelist)) {..} else {..}`

Answer (score 1):

I assume $whitelist is only for security?

You could try something like this:

```
if(isset($_GET['theme'])) {
    foreach ($whitelist as $wlist) {
        if($wlist == $_GET['theme']) {
            echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/'.$_GET['theme'].'.css" />';
            break;
        }
    }
}
else {
    echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/default.css" />';
}
```

If you dont have many styles and if you dont want to add many more you could use "switch" - http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

like this:

```
if(isset($_GET['theme'])) {
switch ($_GET['theme']) {
    case "styleone":
        echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/styleone.css" />';
        break;
    case "styletwo":
        echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/styletwo.css" />';
        break;
    case "another":
        echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/another.css" />';
        break;
    case "andonemore":
        echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/andonemore.css" />';
        break;
    default:
        echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/default.css" />';
        break;
}
}
else { 
    echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/default.css"/>';
}
```